# Determine if the point-estimation is unbiased [Bias of an estimator]

Tags: statistics, parameter-estimation

**The problem:**

> Let x<sub>1</sub>, x<sub>2</sub>, x<sub>3</sub>, ..., x<sub>7</sub> be observations of the independent random variables X<sub>1</sub>, X<sub>2</sub>, X<sub>3</sub>, ..., X<sub>7</sub>, such that E(X<sub>i</sub>) = μ and Var(X<sub>i</sub>) = σ<sup>2</sup>

> Let 
>   `σobs2 = c(x22 + x62 - ½((x1 + x7)2)` 
>
>  Be the point-estimation of σ<sup>2</sup>

> Determine the constant c so that `σobs2` becomes unbiased.

**Here is my attempt:**
E(σ<sub>obs</sub><sup>2</sup>) = cE(x<sub>2</sub><sup>2</sup> + x<sub>6</sub><sup>2</sup> - ½((x<sub>1</sub> + x<sub>7</sub>)<sup>2</sup>)) = c(E(x<sub>2</sub><sup>2</sup>) + E(x<sub>6</sub><sup>2</sup>) - E(½((x<sub>1</sub> + x<sub>7</sub>)<sup>2</sup>)) = 
 c(E(x<sub>2</sub><sup>2</sup>) + E(x<sub>6</sub><sup>2</sup>) - ½E((x<sub>1</sub> + x<sub>7</sub>)<sup>2</sup>))) = c(E(x<sub>2</sub><sup>2</sup>) + E(x<sub>6</sub><sup>2</sup>) - ½E(x<sub>1</sub><sup>2</sup> - 2x<sub>1</sub>x<sub>7</sub><sup>2</sup> + x<sub>7</sub><sup>2</sup>)) = 
 c(E(x<sub>2</sub><sup>2</sup>) + E(x<sub>6</sub><sup>2</sup>) - ½(E(x<sub>1</sub><sup>2</sup>) -2E(x<sub>1</sub>x<sub>7</sub>) + E(x<sub>7</sub><sup>2</sup>))) = ...

This is where  I get stuck, is there anyone who can give me a hint? I am trying to get E(σ<sub>obs</sub><sup>2</sup>) = σ<sup>2</sup>
I am really thankful for any help or advice on this.

**Update:**

 E(σ<sub>obs</sub><sup>2</sup>) = cE(x<sub>2</sub><sup>2</sup> + x<sub>6</sub><sup>2</sup> - ½((x<sub>1</sub> + x<sub>7</sub>)<sup>2</sup>)) = c(E(x<sub>2</sub><sup>2</sup>) + E(x<sub>6</sub><sup>2</sup>) - E(½((x<sub>1</sub> + x<sub>7</sub>)<sup>2</sup>)) = 
 c(E(x<sub>2</sub><sup>2</sup>) + E(x<sub>6</sub><sup>2</sup>) - ½E((x<sub>1</sub> + x<sub>7</sub>)<sup>2</sup>))) = c(E(x<sub>2</sub><sup>2</sup>) + E(x<sub>6</sub><sup>2</sup>) - ½E(x<sub>1</sub><sup>2</sup> - 2x<sub>1</sub>x<sub>7</sub><sup>2</sup> + x<sub>7</sub><sup>2</sup>)) = 
 c(E(x<sub>2</sub><sup>2</sup>) + E(x<sub>6</sub><sup>2</sup>) - ½(E(x<sub>1</sub><sup>2</sup>) -2E(x<sub>1</sub>x<sub>7</sub>) + E(x<sub>7</sub><sup>2</sup>))) = 
 c(E(x<sub>2</sub><sup>2</sup>) + E(x<sub>6</sub><sup>2</sup>) - ½(E(x<sub>1</sub><sup>2</sup>) -2E(x<sub>1</sub>)E(x<sub>7</sub>) + E(x<sub>7</sub><sup>2</sup>))) = 
 c(E(x<sub>2</sub><sup>2</sup>) + E(x<sub>6</sub><sup>2</sup>) - ½E(x<sub>1</sub><sup>2</sup>) + E(x<sub>1</sub>)E(x<sub>7</sub>) - ½E(x<sub>7</sub><sup>2</sup>)) =  
 c(E(x<sub>2</sub><sup>2</sup>) + E(x<sub>6</sub><sup>2</sup>) - ½E(x<sub>1</sub><sup>2</sup>) + E(x<sub>1</sub>)E(x<sub>7</sub>) - ½E(x<sub>7</sub><sup>2</sup>)) = 
 c(V(x<sub>2</sub>) + E<sup>2</sup>(x<sub>2</sub>) + V(x<sub>6</sub>) + E<sup>2</sup>(x<sub>6</sub>) - ½V(x<sub>1</sub>) + -½E<sup>2</sup>(x<sub>1</sub>) + E(x<sub>1</sub>)E(x<sub>7</sub>) - ½V(x<sub>7</sub>) - ½ E<sup>2</sup>(x<sub>7</sub>)) = 
 c(V(x<sub>2</sub>) + V(x<sub>6</sub>) - ½V(x<sub>1</sub>) - ½V(x<sub>7</sub>) + E<sup>2</sup>(x<sub>2</sub>) + E<sup>2</sup>(x<sub>6</sub>) -½E<sup>2</sup>(x<sub>1</sub>) - ½ E<sup>2</sup>(x<sub>7</sub>) + E(x<sub>1</sub>)E(x<sub>7</sub>)) = 
 c(σ<sup>2</sup> + σ<sup>2</sup> - ½σ<sup>2</sup> - ½σ<sup>2</sup> + μ<sup>2</sup> + μ<sup>2</sup> - ½μ<sup>2</sup> - ½ μ<sup>2</sup> + μ<sup>2</sup>)= 
 c(σ<sup>2</sup> + σ<sup>2</sup> - σ<sup>2</sup> + μ<sup>2</sup> + μ<sup>2</sup> - μ<sup>2</sup> + μ<sup>2</sup>) = 
 c(σ<sup>2</sup> + μ<sup>2</sup> + μ<sup>2</sup>) = 
 c(σ<sup>2</sup> + 2μ<sup>2</sup>)

Comment: You can use that for any random variable $X$, it holds that $\mathrm{E}[X^2]=\mathrm{Var}[X] + (\mathrm{E}(X))^2$.

Comment: @AndreasLenz What do I do in the case of E(x₁x₇) ? :)

Comment: For two independent variables $X,Y$ it holds that $\mathrm{E}[XY] = \mathrm{E}[X]\mathrm{E}[Y]$.

Comment: @AndreasLenz Hi, I have  now updated the post, and I get c(σ2 + 2(μ^2)), is this correct? or am I doing it wrong? :)